# Why can't I connect to VMWare guest ubuntu via Telnet nor SSH from host?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ssh, vmware-workstation, telnet

**My host system: Win7(x64) with VMware Workstation 12**

```
VMware Ethernet Network Adapter VMnet1:
    IPv4: 162.168.86.1
    Mask: 255.255.255.0
    Gateway:

VMware Ethernet Network Adapter VMnet8:
    IPv4: 162.168.17.1
    Mask: 255.255.255.0
    Gateway:
```

**Virtual Machine: Lubuntu 16.04 (x64)**

```
ens33     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:19:0f:d6:b8  
          inet addr:128.128.129.232  Bcast:128.128.129.255  Mask:255.255.254.0

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
```

*Virtual Machine Settings... Network Adapter=Bridged(Automatic)*

I've tried access via Telnet from the host machine to the virtual machine with PuTTY:
Destination (IP address)=128.128.129.232 Port=23
And via SSH, on port=22

but the result is the same:
this msgbox

> "PuTTY Fatal Error", "Network error: Connection refused"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu comes with ssh server or telnet service uninstalled.

I've installed openssh-server, then I can connect with ssh port 22.

```
sudo apt-get install ssh
```

Answer (score -1):

This error often occurs due to the IP conflict. Assigning static IP address to Ubuntu should fix the issue.

http://www.doublecloud.org/2013/03/configure-static-ip-address-on-linux-vm-in-vmware-player/

Comment: I can ping the guest from the the host, and viceversa.  So there isn't a IP conflict.